# creating a video by combining audio and one image file using movie.py in python and I am getting my video file but without audio

Tags: python, audio, video

I am trying to create a video by combining audio and one image file using movie.py in python and I am getting my video file but without audio. Help me, please!

Code:

```
import moviepy.editor as mpy
import os

directory_root = os.path.join("R:/", "Rajat", "voices", "same images")
files = os.listdir(directory_root)
files = [os.path.join(directory_root, f) for f in files]

clip = mpy.ImageSequenceClip(files, fps=10)
# clip = mpy.ImageSequenceClip("R:\\Rajat\\voices\\same images\\*.jpg", fps=10)
audio = (mpy.AudioFileClip("play.mp3") 
            .set_duration(clip.duration))
# clip.audio = audio
clip.set_audio = audio
clip.write_videofile("my_video1.mp4")
```

Error:

```
I am getting my video file but without audio
```

Help me, please.

Answer (score -1):

`ImageSequenceClip` expects a list of files. You can find all files in a directory by

```
import os

directory_root = os.path.join("R:/", "Rajat", "voices", "same images")
files = os.listdir(directory_root)
files = [os.path.join(directory_root, f) for f in files]
```

Then, try

```
clip = mpy.ImageSequenceClip(files, fps=10)
```

**Edit 1**:

From a previous comment of yours that was deleted, it seems like you are also missing codecs. Consider installing [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) on your system.

Next, you need to find the location of the `magick.exe` (should be somewhere in `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick...\magick.exe`. Once you found that path, you need to make it visible in your program:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\ImageMagick...\magick.exe")
```

Try again to export your video, please try also exporting it as `mp4` if `avi` does not work.

**Edit 2**:

Great, now that the codec is working, it seems like you need to set the audio differently. You're currently using `clip.set_audio = audio` which actually overwrites the `set_audio` function. Instead, try

```
clip.set_audio(audio)
```

Comment: @RajatSaini I think you accidentally didn't link anything

Comment: No it's not like that but after trying for 3 days on one topic and getting errors.

Comment: @RajatSaini Please see my updated answer. Please also edit your question so others can see the codec error.

Comment: Now I am not Getting that codec error after your guidance, and I am getting my video file successfully but without audio. See the code in my edited question.

Comment: @RajatSaini Great, please see Edit 2 in my answer.

Comment: It is still converting video with no audio.

Comment: note that I am using one Image for 10 minutes of audio.

Comment: How long is the video or how many images do you have?